# Вызов метода из существующего метода

Tags: c#

Не получается разобраться, каким образом при вызове метода передать в него параметр, кроме как указать его явно в первом методе.
Задумка задачи, создать в отдельном  классе Two метод one(), который должен вызвать уже существующий метод класса One, чтобы не дублировать код.

```
class One
{        
    public static double one(Two two)
    {
        // Всё, что пришло в голову это - задать явно значения: 
        // two.X = 1; two.Y = 1;
        return two.X + two.Y;
    }
}
class Two
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public double one()
    {
        return One.one(this);
    }
}
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {            
        Console.WriteLine(new Two().two());
    }
}
```

Comment: `(new Two(){ X = 1, Y = 2 }).one()`

Comment: Ваш код выглядит бессмысленным. Какую задачу решаете? Что сделать хотите эти кодом? Где изначально было дублирование? Как выглядел начальный код?

Comment: Ну дык после того, как вы создали экземпляр, задайте значения его полям: `new Two() { X = 1, Y =1 };`

Comment: У вас в объекте дефолтные значения полей, или используйте инициализатор объектов как указали выше или принимайте значения `x` и `y` в качестве параметров в конструктор. Бтв публичные поля это плохо, используйте хотя бы свойства.

Comment: Да и идея передавать себя в метод другого класса чисто чтобы провести операции над своими же полями выглядит как-то странно в этом случае...